# Multi-stage build cannot copy from previous stage - File not found

Tags: docker

I have the docker file as follows:

```
FROM node:8 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./src/register_form/package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ./src/register_form .
RUN  yarn build

FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.10.0-gpu-py3
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/register_form/build/index.html /app/src/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["/app/src/main.pyc"]
```

However, it cannot copy the index.html from the builder stage. Although when I list the folder in the first stage, the files are there.

The error is:

```
Step 8/22 : COPY --from=builder ./register_form/build/ /app/src/

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5470e05501898502b3aa437639f975ca3e4bfb5a1e897281e62e07ab89866304/merged/register_form/build: no such file or directory
```

How can I fix this problem - the COPY --from=builder docker command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misusing `COPY` command. As it is told in docs:

> If `src` is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are
>   copied, including filesystem metadata.
>
> Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

So your command `COPY ./src/register_form .` does NOT create `register_form` folder in container, but instead copies all contents. You can try adding:

```
RUN ls .
```

to your `Dockerfile` to make sure.

As noticed by @BMitch in comments, you can explicitly set destination folder name  to achieve expected results:

```
COPY ./src/register_form/ register_form/
```

Comment: The command you want is `COPY ./src/register_form/ register_form/`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I haven't noticed that the folder wasn't created by the COPY command.